# Measure dynamic comparator's offset voltage

Tags: circuit-analysis, analog, clock, comparator, dc-offset

I'm trying to characterize a comparator I built and I am wondering how I can plot offset voltage over time. I would like to eventually add a calibration block that will reduce the comparator offset and I need to see how if it is decreasing.

The topology I would like to eventually implement is from this paper ([Fig.11 on page 9](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/7994614)):
[image]

Comment: Can you add a link to the full paper?

Comment: @nanofarad Added

Comment: Why can't you use an off the shelf commercial comparative with full data sheet figures already defined?

Comment: I am designing a chip for a project and I need to design a custom comparator for a SAR ADC @Andyaka